# Method for storing users passwords for other services

Tags: security, encryption, aes, sha

I run a service that integrates with a few other cloud platforms via their apis.  In order to do this, we have to store the login credentials for OTHER sites in our database. Obviously security is a bit of a risk here.

So far, we have been storing the passwords using AES encryption and a salted version of the user's password(for our site) as the cipher.  When a user requests something from the api, they must input their password.  The password checked for validity against the sha hash that we store, and once confirmed, is used to decrypt the password.

The problem is, we would like to start offering a service that retrieves data from the apis we interact with at scheduled intervals(outside the scope of synchronous user requests.).  If we do this, our current security structure will no longer be viable.

My question is, are there any ways to allow for this type of api interaction without storing recoverable versions the passwords in our database?  If not, what are my options for securely storing passwords?

Comment: "salted version of the user's password(for our site) as the cipher" -- do you mean to say the "key" for the cipher?  So, something like k = SaltedHash( salt, user password for your site) is the key used to decrypt the password for the other site?  Additionally, you are storing SHA( user password for your site )?  That would worry me if it is the case...  Please be more precise on the details.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  The key is the salted password used to log in to our site.  Since the password/salt for our site is stored separately from the encrypted credentials for the other sites, this adds an extra layer of security.   As for storing the user passwords for our site, we store a cryptographic hash generated using SHA256.  This is, as far as i know, standard practice

Comment: So if I get hold of your database, I can do a dictionary attack on passwords for your site because it is just SHA256(user password), not anything like PBKDF2, which is intended to resist dictionary attacks.  Once I have the password for the user on your site, then I can derive the key for the other site.  Is that wrong?  My point is that you should be using something like PBKDF2 on the passwords for your site as well.

Answer (score 0):

> we would like to start offering a service that retrieves data from the apis we interact with at scheduled intervals(outside the scope of synchronous user requests.).

This is what the OAuth protocol is designed for. The [OAuth 2.0 code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-24) gives a client application an access token and a refresh token. The refresh token allows the application to get an access token even when the user is not there to authorize the request.

Comment: OAuth would certainly be preferable, however, the platforms I'm pulling information from don't use it.

Comment: Well, if those platforms only support basic scheme authentication (sending username and password with each request), then there is no really secure way of doing this. You could use a machine credential to encrypt a list of username/passwords, but there's no way to secure it so that only your service can access those credentials.

Comment: That's sort of what I figured.  But I was hoping there was some other solution I wasn't seeing.